# Excel: using formula for cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to use the =MAX() function but get the start and stop cell from cell values:

Given cell-values like this:

A1 = 110 (the row start)

A2 = 130 (the row end)

A3 = 4   (the column-id ie "D")

Using this the max function should become

MAX(D110:D130)

When I change the cell values the range MAX uses should change. Any way to do this? INDIRECT seems useful but i cannot make it work. Im using the same worksheet for everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
= MAX(INDEX($A:$XFD,A1,A3):INDEX($A:$XFD,A2,A3))
```

Quick note: `INDIRECT` should be avoided because it is volatile. `INDEX` is preferred.

Comment: Yes this works! Care to explain the first parameter? $A:$XFD This is also transposed to something else when i paste it into my excel (but it works!) Its transposed into $1:$1048576

Comment: @HerrErik `XFD` is the last column in the worksheet so `$A:$XFD` means "*select the full columns A through XFD*" and `1048576` is the last row in the worksheet so `$1:$1048576` means "*select the full rows 1 through 1048576*", so they both refer to the same range, that being the entire worksheet. I usually just do `$A:$XFD` just because it is shorter to type haha.

Comment: `$A:$XFD` and `$1:$1048576` are references to the whole sheet (it's the same as writing `$A$1:$XFD$1048576`).  `A1` will then give the row number and `A3` the column.  `=INDEX($1:$1048576,3,4)` will be a reference to D3 - row 3, column 4.  The second INDEX performs the same to return a second cell giving a complete start/end range.  `MAX` then returns the maximum value in that range (soz, got distracted and didn't realise @ImaginaryHuman072889 had already replied).

Comment: Why cannot i use something like simply: INDEX(A1,A3). Why do i need to first specify a range? Specifying the column and row gives all the info the function needs, right?

Comment: @HerrErik "*Why do I need to first specify a range?*" How else would `INDEX` know where to look? What if you had an identical problem except that you wanted to find the `MAX` of a range defined this way *in a different sheet*. In that case, the formula would be: `= MAX(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$XFD,A1,A3):INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$XFD,A2,A3))` (for example). Notice how this formula is identical but the range is a different sheet.

Comment: That's a good point. But if its the same sheet (which it often is) then it seems very unnecessary to need to specify "the entire sheet". Leaving it at zero should be just that --> INDEX(0,A1,A3).

Comment: @HerrErik Referencing the entire sheet in `INDEX` is pretty rare. The range used in `INDEX` is usually an entire row or column (e.g. `$A:$A`). Or sometimes just a small matrix (e.g. `$A$1:$C$3`). A range doesn't even have to be references to a cell. It could just be hardcoded. (e.g. a range could be `{1;5;3}`). Even in your example here `INDEX(0,A1,A3)`, `0` is a valid range. A range **must** be specified with `INDEX`.